# How to add KeyUp event to dynamically added INPUT

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-events

There is a table that has dynamically added rows in this way:

```
var hTML=   '<tr> \
            <td class="cell1"><input id="tblJENazwa-' + i + '" type="text" style="background-color: #f0f0f0;" disabled></input></td> \
            <td class="cell2"><input id="tblJEKalorie-' + i + '" type="text" style="background-color: #f0f0f0;" disabled></input></td> \
            <td class="cell2"><input id="tblJEWaga-' + i + '" class="JEWedit" type="number" min="0"></input></td> \
            </tr>'
$('#tblJadlospisEdycjaT1 tbody').append(hTML);
```

The input that I need the data from is #tblJEWaga-'i' where 'i' is is between 0 and 100+, and has class .JEWedit
I wanted to use this class and create an even handler for KeyUp event.
I tried to do this in the following way:

```
$('.JEWedit').keyup(function(){
        clearTimeout(typingTimer);
        console.log("attr ID=",$(this).attr('id'));
        if ($('.JEWedit').val()) {
            typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTypingT, doneTypingInterval);
        }
    });
```

...but... this does not work at all.

Could you please advice on how to create on KeyUp event handler in order to track #tblJEWaga-'i' changes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where [Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) comes in handy. Since there are unknown (0 or more) `.JEWedit` elements available when your page loads, defining your event as `$('.JEWedit').keyup()` won't work for any that are added after the fact. Simply define your event as such:

```
$('body').on('keyup', '.JEWedit', function () {
  clearTimeout(typingTimer);
  console.log("attr ID=", $(this).attr('id'));
  if ($('.JEWedit').val()) {
    typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTypingT, doneTypingInterval);
  }
}
```

Now, this `keyup` event will be available to any `.JEWedit`, so long as it is appended anywhere in your `<body>` element.